# Node website gives error on the server that doesn't exist on localhost. The files are the same

Tags: node.js, github, express-handlebars

I am developing a website on localhost:3000. Everything works fine. I've added another query and it's loading properly. When I push to AWS server via github I'm getting an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

In routes I have added only mygraph4, everything was working properly on the server before.

```
Promise.all([queries.queryTable(thequery1), queries.queryTable(thegraphquery), queries.queryTable(thegraphquery2), queries.queryTable(thegraphquery3), queries.queryTable(thegraphquery4)])
    .then(
        data =>
        res.render('tabs', {
            'mydata2': JSON.stringify(data[0]),
            'mydata1': JSON.stringify(data[1]),
            'mygraph2': JSON.stringify(data[2]),
            'mygraph3': JSON.stringify(data[3]),
            'mygraph4': JSON.stringify(data[4]),
            'mylittleuser': req.app.locals.myuser
        })

    );
```

On view.handlebars

```
var myjsongraphdata4 = {{{mygraph4}}}; this comes empty on the production server.
```

I've checked the files on the production server and they are the same. My only idea is to delete the whole project on the server and pull it again from github but maybe this time will get even more issues.

Why does it refuse to load the last query? It's using the same database, same table, same connection as the other queries that are working.

Comment: have you tried logging the data

Comment: I figured out how to fix it:
`pm2 restart app`